# Why didn't Anakin/Darth Vader turn back to the light when he caused so much suffering?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader

In RoTS, Ani just wanted to 'save Padmé's life'. When he met Obi-Wan on Mustafar, he truly believed that he was in the right and that his friends were the traitors to the Republic (thanks to Palpatine's exquisite web of manipulation). So, after he harmed/killed so many beings, why didn't he figure out that something was dreadfully wrong and Palpatine was just seeking personal power? Was it that after discovering the power that came with the dark side he became addicted/wanted power for himself?

Comment: Forever will it dominate your destiny.

Comment: Legends lore: He couldn't beat Palpatine because he was dependant on electronics, which didn't like Palpatines force lightning. But we can see him plotting against him or keeping artifacts from him on many occasions. But he was still consumed by the dark side, until the event known as... Death Star black suits only wrestling match.